# node express routing params not catching

Tags: angularjs, express, parameters

I have this

```
    router.put('/user:resourceId', function(req, res) {

        User.findOneAndUpdate({resourceId: req.params.resourceId}, req.body, function(err, user) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.send(user);
        });
    });
```

and in my angular code I have

```
    updateResource: function(resource){
        var self = this;
        return $http.put('api/resources/resource', resource, {params:{resourceId:resource.resourceId}}).then(function(response){
            return response.data;
        }, function(err){
            $log.error('Error updating', err);
        });
    }
```

Why isn't this path catching? It works when I remove the params.

Answer (score 1):

Your route looks a little off, try the following:

```
router.put('/user/:resourceId', function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

For a URL that looks like: `/user/123`, where `req.param.resourceId` is 123.

It looks like your angular code is pointing to `/api/resources/resource` though, so I can understand why it's perhaps not matching your Express route for `/user/:resourceId` - (Unless your Express router is set to handle request for something like the following: `/api/resources/resource/user/:resourceid`?

Comment: I ended up just removing the query and sending a body, which worked. Didn't have time to figure out why. I'll revisit this next week tho.